# INDEX ON Date Range and a Uniqe Number VFP

Tags: sorting, select, indexing, visual-foxpro

I need to change a select statement in VFP to do a simple task (select all records in a date range and by a Employee Number). I have tried everything I can think of. I know I can do it in SQL select but I just want to use the table I have and not a cursor.

I'm trying something like this

```
INDEX ON Date >= ThisForm.DateFrom+Date + Date=< ThisForm.DateTo+ALLTRIM(empid) TAG MyOrder
```

I know how `INDEX ON` works but my format is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you meant a filtered index. However you don't need to do such a thing. You could simply have an index combining employee number (I suppose it is an integer) and the date. Then you can use a simple for and while scoping clauses or range or alike (you really didn't explain what you would do) - and even an SQL might be the easier way depending on what you would do.
ie: (using date as a column name is a bad idea, but that is another matter)

```
INDEX ON padl(empId, 10, '1') + dtoc(Date,1) TAG MyOrder
```

Having such an index you could scan all the records for a given employee in a date range like this:

```
local lnEmployee, lcStart, lcEnd
lnEmployee = 1 && whatever the employee number is
lcStart = padl(m.lnEmployee, 10, '1')+dtoc(ThisForm.DateFrom,1)
lcEnd   = padl(m.lnEmployee, 10, '1')+dtoc(ThisForm.DateTo,1)

scan for padl(empId, 10, '1') + dtoc(Date,1) >= m.lcStart and ;
   padl(empId, 10, '1') + dtoc(Date,1) <= m.lcEnd
* whatever
endscan
```

This would do the same:

```
local lnEmployee, lcStart, lcEnd
lnEmployee = 1 && whatever the employee number is
lcStart = padl(m.lnEmployee, 10, '1')+dtoc(ThisForm.DateFrom,1)
lcEnd   = padl(m.lnEmployee, 10, '1')+dtoc(ThisForm.DateTo,1)
set order to tag myOrder
set range to m.lcStart, m.lcEnd
scan
* whatever
endscan
```

PS: Actually with indexes on empid and date, a simple scan for ... would do too. ie:

```
scan for empId = m.lnEmpoyee and ;
         Date >= ThisForm.DateFrom and ;
         Date <= ThisForm.DateTo
    *...
endscan
```

Comment: Snap thanks ill try some of those they may be a better solutions thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Welp don't really like filter but if any one has a better idea let me know!

```
Set Filter To Date >= ThisForm.DateFrom .And. Date =< ThisForm.DateTo .And. EmpID = AllTrim(ThisForm.Combo1.Value)
```

Comment: If you're going to use set filter, make sure you do an empty 'set filter to' and then the actual 'set filter' statement.  Unless VFP has changed, that used to return some strange results for me.